# I have a EditText and RecyclerView in a same screen, If user click on TagPeople icon, the recycler should come from bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have an `EditText` and a `RecyclerView` in the same screen. If the user click on the tag people icon, the `RecyclerView` should appear from the top of the `tagPlaceholder` view and grows until the bottom of the `creatorContainer` view. When the RecyclerView visibility is set to `View.GONE`, the `creatorContainer` view should appear next to the close button.

Screen Layout:

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_48"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_zero"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_small"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/screenTitle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_zero"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/label_create_post"
        android:textAppearance="@style/SubtitleAppearance"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/closeButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/submitPost"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/closeButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/closeButton"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/submitPost"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_48"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_huge"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:text="@string/label_post"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/screenTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/screenTitle"
        style="@style/PrimaryButton"
        />
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/creatorEditorContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/peopleList"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/closeButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_big"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/creatorContainer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            >
          <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
              android:id="@+id/postCreatorImage"
              android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40"
              android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_larger"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_man"
              tools:src="@drawable/ic_man"
              />
          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/creatorName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:textAppearance="@style/SubtitleAppearance"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Name"
                tools:text="Mahesh Nandam"
                />
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/creatorDesignation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_big"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrey"
                android:text="peopleDesignation"
                tools:text="Senior Development Engineer"
                style="@style/BodyAppearanceRegular"
                />
          </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/feedInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/compose_hint"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_larger"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_larger"
            android:textAppearance="@style/BodyAppearanceRegular"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextGrey"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/creatorContainer"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
            tools:text="Calling all ML and AI enthusiasts."
            />
      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/peopleList"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_zero"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_zero"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tagPlaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/creatorEditorContainer"
        tools:itemCount="7"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_people_profile_meta"
        app:adapter="@{fragFeedViewModel.getAdapterPeopleListAdapter()}" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/tagPlaceholder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&#64;"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:textAppearance="@style/BodyAppearanceRegular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_zero"
        />
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/tagInput"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_zero"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tagPlaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tagPlaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tagPlaceholder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/cameraBtn"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:hint="@string/hint_tag"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@style/BodyAppearanceRegular"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/cameraBtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_24"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_24"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_big"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_big"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tagInput"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tagInput"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tagInput"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/galleryBtn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/galleryBtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_24"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_big"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_gallery"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_14"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cameraBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/cameraBtn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/cameraBtn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"/>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the screenshot below, the `creatorEditorContainer` view is sticking to the middle of the screen.

In the below image the RecyclerView visibility is gone.

The `creatorEditorContainer` view has to be positioned just next to  the `closeButton` view, please help me to achieve this.

I have placed the constraint of `creatorEditorContainer` to the top_to_bottom of `closeButton` and bottom_to_top of RecyclerView

And the `layout_height` property is set to `0dp` so the `creatorEditorContainer` view is positioned to the middle of the `closeButton` view and the `RecyclerView`, help me to move the `creatorEditorContainer` view next to the `closeButton` view without dragging to the center of the screen.

[image: Screenshot of Design Editor in Android Studio]

[image: Another screenshot of Design Editor in Android Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bottom_to_top` constraint of the `RecyclerView`

and add the `layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` of recycler view to be `creatorEditorContainer`

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/creatorEditorContainer"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tagPlaceholder"
```

Comment: RecyclerView  is completely covering the entire screen